JWSMWQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager remotely fails but local works fine
As stated in my title. I am trying to connect to my IBM queue and locally this works all fine. The moment I try to do it remotely with all the same settings etc it fails given the known error JWMSWQ0018 JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'queue' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'Client'.
I can duplicate this error locally by not passing my trustStore so I guess this has something to do with it, but I just point to the exact same trustStore I use locally.
I've read many questions and answers about this, but I still hope to find my answer or new insights because I have absolutely no clue why its not working
thanks

Well, the message you've posted states the connection failed and with just that information it's hard to tell you more. I'm pretty sure there is more information about this, e.g. in stack trace, your code etc. Running stuff remotely is often quite different from doing so locally, e.g. you have an entire network in between which might include proxies, firewalls etc., security settings on servers are normally higher than on local machines etc.

Is that message exactly as it came out, or have you changed some of the variable values? The hostname of 'Client' looks likely to be a problem if that is the real value (assuming that your qmgr isn't running on a host called Client).
The JMSWMQ0018 message is generally associated with a JMSException which should also contain an error code and a linked exception to give more details.
See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=jms-handling-checked-exceptions for information on how to extract those details.

Can you update your question with the actual invocation of the program in both the local and client cases, and in the case where you said you can duplicate the error locally. Show us all output too please.

@DougBurns Its not a JSMException which is weird. I just get the error I linked.

If the output from the application only shows the message you provided, then I suspect your application is catching the JMSException and only printing out the message attribute of the exception.
You may need to modify the application to print more of the diagnostic details.
For example, using a catch block with:
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
will print both the message and the stack trace for the JMSException and linked exceptions.

The Keystore I used locally was different from the one on the server I used remotely.
The latter one was expired.
So a simple change replacement of the outdated keystore on the server with the correct one did it.
